# Retrieve password stored in db

Tags: laravel-5

I created user profile for my application. In this user profile, user can update their information just like email address, password, position, company name .. etc. If user want to change one of their information, user need to provide current password. And I will verify current password user provided is correct or not. Error is I can't verify the current password user provided. Below is the part of my user controller codes.

```
if($request['current_pwd'])
        {
            if($request['new_pwd'])
            {
                if($user->password == bcrypt($request['current_pwd']))
                {
                    $user->password = bcrypt($request['new_pwd']);
                }else{
                    return redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'Wrong current password !']);
                }
            }elseif($user->password == bcrypt($request['current_pwd']))
            {
                $user->save();
            }else{
                return redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'Wrong Current Password ! Check Again!']);
            }
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'Please enter your current password !']);
        }
```

if the user want to change their current password, user must enter current password, new password, . If current password is equal the password stored in db, the new password will be update. If not, return with messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this
first include Hash namespace in your controller,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

and use the following condition to make sure the current password is entered is valid

```
 if($request->has('current_password')){
        $current_password = $request->input('current_password');
        if(!Hash::check($current_password,Auth::user()->password)){
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([
                'current_password' => 'You current password doesnot match with the logined user\'s !'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should match the encrypted "current password" entry with the password the user already has. You can get the user's password by using the function `Auth::user()`

So your condition would be:

```
if(bcrypt($request['current_pwd']) == Auth::user()) {
    // Do password change
} else {
    // Invalid password error
}
```

There is another function: `getAuthPassword()` which you can use by specifying the user ID, like so:

```
$user = User::find('1');
$user->getAuthPassword();
```

This will get the password for user ID 1

Comment: Using `getAuthPassword()` will require you to use it with the user ID. Did you try `Auth::user()`?

Comment: Yes, ofcoz , here is part of my codes , '{ $user = User::where('id', $id) }' then $user->getAuthPassword(). But It is not ok

Comment: If you already have `$id` set, have you tried running directly on that? As `$id->getAuthPassword()`?

Answer (score 0):

Due to **salting**! this kind of `$user->password == bcrypt($request['current_pwd']` checking will not work!

> Try making hash of same password you will get different hash!

So Check like this in laravel 5.2

```
$crypt = new Hashing\BcryptHasher();
$match = $crypt->check($user->password, $request['current_pwd']);
```